# WiX - Writing new file from Custom Action

Tags: c#, wix

I have a C# Custom Action that loads an XML document and makes some changes to its contents.

When I run this on my Windows 7 32-bit workstation, the new XML document is not created.  When I test the installer on a Windows Server 2003 VM, the CA works as expected and saves the XML document in the installation directory.

```
string configFile = Path.Combine(configFileSaveLocation, targetName);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(configFile);
doc.Save(writer);
writer.Close();
```

where 'doc' is an XmlDocument.

No exceptions are caught if I put the above 4 lines in a try/catch block.

Any thoughts as to what I'm missing?

Comment: Its probably a permission issue. Windows 7 is equiped with UAC. Are you sure there is no exception? Also, you should try to surround the StreamWriter with a 'using' statement.

Comment: It could also be saving the file to an unexpected location.  How is configFileSaveLocation defined?

Comment: Why are you not using the standard XmlConfig or XmlFile elements? They resolve most of such problems under the hood...

Comment: Did you try setting Impersonate to "no"?

Comment: My first thought was also that this was a UAC issue. However, when I added the try/catch and ran it in the debugger, no security exceptions were thrown.

Comment: @Impersonate="No" did the trick. I haven't had to worry about UAC very much to date - I would have thought I would have encountered a security exception.  Cosmin - did you want to submit this as an answer that I can accept?

Comment: Hi Yan - I will look into that a little more, but these are pre-existing config files and processing logic that I'm recycling in the CA.

Comment: Richard: the save file location was basically just INSTALLLOCATION. The same install was running fine in a different environment, so I didn't think it was a logic bug on the save location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Impersonate="No" did the trick, it's clearly a permissions issue. But that alone leaves the lack of exception unexplained. Windows Vista and later will redirect certain kinds of bad file accesses to `%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore\Program Files*`. I bet if you look there instead of the real `Program Files*` you will see your configuration file.

While researching this I just learned one easy way to get there is to look in the real folder and click the `Compatibility files` button in Explorer; the button only appears when relevant. See Scenario 2 on [Common file and registry virtualization issues in Windows Vista or in Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387) for details.

Comment: Nice! Exactly as you described.