# Wix: Write File in Custom Action

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

i got a problem with *wix* and managed custom actions: in my custom action i create a file and save it in the *INSTALLLOCATION* path. It seems like it works, no exception is thrown. But after the installation, the just created File not exists in the *INSTALLLOCATION*.

WiX-File:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetInstallPath" Property="CreateTimeStamp" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]"
   Execute="immediate"/>
<CustomAction Id="CreateTimeStamp" BinaryKey="SetupActions.dll"  
   DllEntry="CreateTimeStampFile" Execute="deferred" Return="check"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetInstallPath" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
  <Custom Action="CreateTimeStamp" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Custom-Action-Methode:

```
...
var keys = new string[session.CustomActionData.Keys.Count];
session.CustomActionData.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);
var cad = keys[0];
var filepath = cad + "myfile.xml";
File.Create(filepath);
...
```

Anyone a idea?

Edited: After the post from Scott Boettger y edited the wix-file content.

Comment: You should accept the answer once you have the working solution. This will help you later on to have more people willing to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think your configuration is correct. Here are some of the problems:

1. You shouldn't use private properties in InstallExecuteSequence (CREATE_TIME_STAMP is better than CreateTimeStamp because it's a public property).
2. You're setting the CreateTimeStamp property and reading CustomActionData inside your custom action. You should set the **CustomActionData** property to the INSTALLLOCATION path.
3. Since your custom action is creating a file in the install folder, it should run as deferred and **Impersonate** attribute should be set to "no". This way it will have enough privileges to create the file.

Try making these modifications and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Hi Cosmin Pirvu, thank you so much for your answer. I sat the impersonate-property and now it works fine! Thank you!

Comment: As a side note: This answer contains a nice gist with a sample http://stackoverflow.com/a/27299522/602449

Answer (score 6):

I believe that your custom actions need to fall between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize. Try this:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetInstallPath" After="InstallInitialize"/>
  <Custom Action="CreateTimeStamp" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. in my post i wrote en error. 
my wix-file looks like this:

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="SetInstallPath" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
      <Custom Action="CreateTimeStamp" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

The Problem I have is, that it looks like all works fine. I get no error and in the log-file i get the messege that the file has been generated.
But after run the file does not exists in the installlocation..

Comment: Change both actions to execute deferred and you also shouldn't have them running at the same time. You currently have them both running Before="InstallFinalize".

Comment: When it was neither giving an error nor working, did you look in the `Compatibility files` area? (%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore\Program Files*\...; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721736/wix-writing-new-file-from-custom-action/5755396#5755396)