# Wix Custom Action Implementation for Writing Installfolder in text

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wix, windows-installer

I have following Wix Code that is supposed to send the value of property to Custom Action Written in C#. Basically what I want is when the MSI is installed, I want to write the path of Folder where Wix installed the program in text file. I referred to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx) site and created code accordingly, but my Custom Action isn't working.

Following is my Wix File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SetupInstallFolder" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="LP" UpgradeCode="9e10a7d8-4ffb-493c-8318-c44ba4bc0c4c">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="no" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupInstallFolder" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupInstallFolder" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="SomeRandomEXE">
        <File Source ="G:\SarVaGYa\myworkspace\LatestLpa\lpa\lpa_c\here\src\lpa\Release\lpa.exe" />
      </Component>      
        </ComponentGroup>
    <Binary Id="SetupCA2"  src="G:\visual studio stuffs\SetupCAInstallFolder\SetupCAInstallFolder\bin\Release\SetupCAInstallFolder.CA.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="INSTALLFOLDERFINDER" Execute="immediate" Property="INSTALLEDPATH" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="INSTALLFOLDERFINDER" Sequence="2"></Custom>

    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I have also given my C# code that is supposed to get the value and write it in file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

namespace SetupCAInstallFolder
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult InstallFolderFinder(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("Here is the SetupCAInstallFolder");
            string path = session["INSTALLEDPATH"];
            session.Log("Installed Path is " + path);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("F:\\pathgenerated.txt", path);
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "installed.txt", "sdkasdkasdlkasdk");

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

The Wix file compiles and gives MSI that doesn't get the value of **INSTALLEDPATH** . If I add **DllEntry="InstallFolderFinder"** in CustomAction tag, it fails with error  **The CustomAction/@DllEntry attribute cannot coexist with a previously specified attribute on this element.  The CustomAction element may only have one of the following target attributes specified at a time: DllEntry, Error, ExeCommand, JScriptCall, Script, Value, or VBScriptCall**

How do I pass the value of INSTALLEDPATH to C# Custom Action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed the issue after stumbling around some more site. I have added the code in gist. The Wix File Code is ***[here](https://gist.github.com/mesarvagya/9f76ccd5c8507df2e3ce)*** and the C# Custom action code is ***[here](https://gist.github.com/mesarvagya/82de65408d5f7fddf681)*** . Basically I added 
two Custom tags in InstallExexuteSequeunce that first loads the dllentry and the second passes the parameter to Custom Action Written in C#.

Comment: Interesting -- I like this solution and I didn't think of using another custom action to set the value based on the UI value. Nice.

Comment: See my comment for my answer. This is a good working example for deferred custom actions (if someone needs deferred CAs).

Answer (score 1):

MSI is determining the paths between the actions `CostInitialize` and `CostFinalize`.
Using hardcoded sequences is very rarely to recommend, and maybe you have chosen the wrong sequence number for this.

Try:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action='INSTALLFOLDERFINDER' After='CostFinalize'></Custom> 
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I hope you are sure, `INSTALLDEDPATH` is your the correct property. The MSI base property for paths is `TARGETDIR.

If it still doesn't work, try a custom action type 51 with setting a property `MYDUMMY` on the value of `[INSTALLEDPATH]`. Now you can see, if at least the value is correctly written in a standard custom action not programmed.

Comment: Philm thanks for your insight. After some googling around, I found the solution.

Comment: Gratulation that it works now. FYI: The solution you found, is a solution for deferred custom actions (as you parametrized in your WiX code: Execute="deferred"). For simply reading properties, deferred custom actions are not very comfortable (as you see, first you need another custom action pushing the necessary properties in there). That's what I mentioned shortly at your last question. For simply reading out properties, it is enough having immediate custom actions, but then you need the correct position in sequence as described in my answer.